# Como hacer caja de codigo con estilo o color-scheme

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Hola compañeros de StackOverFlow, hace un tiempo he querido hacer este estilo de caja de código pero realmente no se como empezar, o que librería me sirve para realizar esto.

Aquí dejo una imagen de lo que quiero poner en mi web.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quedo atento a cualquier pregunta o respuesta.

Comment: Puedes utilizar monaco editor: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Gracias por la recomendación, tu comentario fue de gran utilidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar [Code Mirror](https://codemirror.net/), por ejemplo:

```js
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
  // muestro las líneas de código
  lineNumbers: true,
  // elijo el tema
  theme: 'icecoder',
  // esto deshabilita la opción de reescribir
  readOnly: true
});
```

```html
<!-- fundamental para que funcione -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.38.0/codemirror.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.38.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>

<!-- tema a elección -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.38.0/theme/icecoder.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- librería aceptada a elección -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.38.0/mode/javascript/javascript.min.js"></script>


<h2>Code Mirror</h2>

<textarea id="code" name="code">$(function() {
  $('div#froala-editor').froalaEditor({
    toolbarButtons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
    
    // define new inline styles.
    inlineStyles: {
      'Big Red': 'font-size: 20px; color: red;',
      'Small Blue': 'font-size: 14px; color: blue;'
    }
  });
});</textarea>
```

---

Luego hay más configuración disponible en la [documentación](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#config).

Comment: Excelente, exactamente lo que necesitaba, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Otro que podría usar es [Prism](http://prismjs.com/) el cual cuenta también con [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/prism) lo que facilita su uso directamente

Su uso sería como sigue:

```
<!--Incluir esto en el Head-->
<!--Tema de Color -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.14.0/themes/prism-okaidia.min.css">

<!--Si deseas incluir un botón para facilitar copiar el fragmento de código posteado a tus lectores-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.14.0/plugins/toolbar/prism-toolbar.min.css">

<!--Incluir al final de tu página web con los demás scripts-->
<!--Biblioteca-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.5.0/prism.min.js"></script>

<!--Sintaxis de lenguaje a emplear (en este caso incluí css)-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.14.0/components/prism-css.min.js"></script>

<!--Incluir estos Plugins para que funcione lo de arriba-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.14.0/plugins/toolbar/prism-toolbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.14.0/plugins/copy-to-clipboard/prism-copy-to-clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.14.0/plugins/data-uri-highlight/prism-data-uri-highlight.min.js"></script>
```

Finalmente se usa así con el html

```
<pre><code class="language-css">p { color: red; }</code></pre>
```